# How to train ANN from PCA results?

Tags: neural-network, feature-extraction, multilabel-classification

I have performed PCA to all images of my database so I have different vectors returned from PCA like Egenface mean etc. 
My question is Which vector I would use to train my NN in MATLB? And How would I train NN for 5 clases?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you explain in more detail what it is that you have done, and what the problem is?

Comment: After performing PCA on 26 images I have Eigenfaces matrix with size 65536*25. For training a neural network Should I provid this vector as a input? As it have lot of number of rows?

Comment: Secondly As there were 26 images Why I have matrix of 65536*25?